# Removing all quotations marks from a string (REGEXREPLACE)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working in a Google spreadsheet with a formula. I need to remove all quotation marks `"` from a string in cell A1.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\"","")
```

This formula however doesn't actually escape the quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotation mark with another double quotation mark:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"""","")
```

However, you may use [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) if you just need to replace double quotation marks:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")
```

Comment: Thank you, both work! I don't understand how however. Wouldn't it be supposed to replace all instances of `""` instead of just `"`? Either way, thank you.

Comment: @kpeirt Texts should be coded somehow for a machine to understand that it is some text. Since the `"` used to tell the machine a text starts and ends here, you need to handle `"` inside in a specific way. In GS, e.g., you need to use `""` to tell the machine you have a literal `"` inside the string literal. Same as in C# verbatim string literals, `@""""` would mean a `"` text.

Comment: Interesting +1, the double escaping of quotes is very reminiscent of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; """"; )
```

or:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; CHAR(34); )
```

or replace `SUBSTITUTE` with `REGEXREPLACE`